Why did it take so long for Jitney to appear on Broadway?
The ten plays in August Wilson's Pittsburgh Cycle have all appeared on Broadway, but (table adapted from the one on Wikipedia) spot the odd one out:



Year of premiere
Title
Decade
Opened on Broadway




1982
Jitney
1970s
2017 – Samuel J. Friedman Theatre


1984
Ma Rainey's Black Bottom
1920s
1984 – Cort Theatre


1985
Fences
1950s
1987 – 46th Street Theatre


1986
Joe Turner's Come and Gone
1910s
1988 – Ethel Barrymore


1987
The Piano Lesson
1930s
1990 – Walter Kerr


1990
Two Trains Running
1960s
1992 – Walter Kerr


1995
Seven Guitars
1940s
1996 – Walter Kerr


1999
King Hedley II
1980s
2001 – Virginia Theatre


2003
Gem of the Ocean
1900s
2004 – Walter Kerr


2005
Radio Golf
1990s
2007 – Cort Theatre



Looking at the columns for "Year of premiere" and "Opened on Broadway", they're at most 2-3 years apart except for the very first one, Jitney, which was written in 1979 and first produced in 1982, then opened Off-Broadway in 2000. Despite so many of Wilson's other plays having appeared on Broadway decades earlier, it took until 2017 for Jitney to open there. Why did it take so long? I understand doubt over a first instalment, if Wilson wasn't so well known back then, but 2017 was even more than a decade after his death!

Jitney was essentially written twice, so its long journey towards being performed on Broadway actually includes not one, but two delays.
Wilson completed the first version in 1979, inspired by his rides in jitney cabs while visiting his relatives in Pittsburgh. It was his first attempt at writing a full-length play, and despite being a little rough around the edges, it was picked up by the Allegheny Repertory Theater in Pittsburgh, and with glowing reviews it played to sold-out houses throughout 1982. Unfortunately Wilson did not receive any further offers from companies wanting to stage the play, and so he put it aside in order to concentrate on other projects. This was the first hiatus.
In 1996 Wilson returned to Jitney, having written six more plays in the meantime. In particular he had formed the idea of creating the Century Cycle, consisting of ten plays, each play representing a given decade. When Jitney was first written, Wilson had not had this concept in mind, and so to insert it into the cycle as the representative play of the 1970s the play had to be substantially rewritten. As noted by the August Wilson study group blog:

In revising the script, Wilson beefed up the dialog between Booster
and Becker, the relationship that forms the central plot of the play.
In the original, the Youngblood/Rena relationship was a bit flat and
underdeveloped. In the revised version, Wilson added seven monologues,
producing characters with more fully developed personalities...
Many of the changes Wilson made to Jitney focused... on guaranteeing
the fidelity and authenticity of the characters. Again, now cognizant
that Jitney in its final form would “introduce” the Cycle of plays,
Wilson was careful in the new version of Jitney to insert mention of
characters who would reappear in subsequent plays.

A few years later in April 2000 the revised version of Jitney opened off-Broadway and closed on January 28, 2001. It would seem natural for it to then transfer to Broadway, given its popularity and the fact that Wilson had won two Pulitzer prizes. But the stumbling point was finance. According to an article in the New York Times:

Mr. Wilson's critical accolades have not always translated into strong
sales on Broadway; his last play, "King Hedley II," lost money during
a two-month run at the Virginia Theater in 2001.

It seems that the poor performance of King Hedley II scared off investors, making it impossible to raise the necessary funds to stage Jitney on Broadway. The producer Benjamin Mordecai, who was responsible for producing many of Wilson's play on and off Broadway and in London's West End, was not successful in this case. An article by the theatre critic Don Shewey sadly notes:

While a team of producers devoted to Mr. Wilson's work, headed by Mr.
Mordecai, has been able to raise the financing to put "King Hedley II"
on Broadway with a theater star, Mr. Mitchell, they were unable to do
so for "Jitney"

These financial problems caused the second hiatus, which lasted until 2017, resulting in the strange event of Jitney having its Broadway debut more than ten years after its author's death.
